# Sed expression just prints entire file

Tags: sed

I've been trying to extract the bold portion from the following:

<a href="**/torrent/4384536/HorribleSubs-Black-Clover-128-720p-mkv**/">[HorribleSubs] Black Clover - 128 [720p].mkv</a>

But for whatever reason, this sed expression-

```
sed --regexp-extended 's#<a href="(/torrent/.+)/">.*</a>#\1#'
```

-is returning the **entire** file, when of course, I only want the `\1` capture group to be.

The weird thing, is that this expression worked just fine when I tried debugging it with [desed](https://github.com/SoptikHa2/desed/); with the capture group and primary match showing up just fine.

I'm using gnu sed 4.8-1

Comment: shouldn't '.+' account for any characters in that space, including a double quote? What is the purpose of explicitly telling sed to disallow a double quote in that space when there is none? Also, unfortunately, it is still outputting the entire file even with your modification.

Comment: Sed will implicitly print every line in the file unless the `-n` command line option is set. Then printing is only effected with the `p` or `P` commands or the `p` flag on the substitute command. Exceptions are the `a`,`i`,`c`,`=` and `F` commands which print the appended, inserted and changed line and current line number or the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -n -E '/.*<a href="(\/torrent\/[^"]*)\/">[^<]*<\/a>.*/{s//\1/p;q}'
```

**Details**:

- `-n` - suppresses default line output
- `-E` - enables POSIX ERE regex syntax
- `/.*<a href="(\/torrent\/[^"]*)\/">[^<]*<\/a>.*/` - finds a line containing `< href=".../">...</a>` substring, capturing the part between `href="` and `/"`
- `{s//\1/p;q}'` - replaces the string matched above with the value of the captured substring, `p`rints it and `q`uits.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Bif7xO):

```sh
s='blah
<a href="/torrent/4384536/HorribleSubs-Black-Clover-128-720p-mkv/">[HorribleSubs] Black Clover - 128 [720p].mkv</a>
blah
<a href="/torrent/1111111/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.mkv/">[HorribleSubs] Black Clover - 128 [720p].mkv</a>
blah'
sed -n -E '/.*<a href="(\/torrent\/[^"]*)\/">[^<]*<\/a>.*/{s//\1/p;q}' <<< "$s"
# => /torrent/4384536/HorribleSubs-Black-Clover-128-720p-mkv
```

Comment: This works, but why doesn't it work when I change the delimiter to '#'?
`sed -n -E '#.*<a href="(/torrent/[^"]*)/">[^<]*</a>.*#{s//\1/p;q}'`

Also, I can understand `[^<]` because it would ensure sed would stop at the right place but why `[^"]*` earlier in the expression?

Comment: @Papu You can't use a `#` as regex delimiter in a non-substitution command unless you escape the first occurrence. `sed -n -E '\#.*<a href="(/torrent/[^"]*)/">[^<]*</a>.*#{s//\1/p;q}'` [will work](https://ideone.com/L2bsGL). `[^"]` matches any char but `"`, so `[^"]*` helps stay within an attribute value and speeds searching up a bit.